# explorer.exe crashing after upgrading to Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, crash

I just upgraded from Windows 7 to 10 after a factory reset of Windows 7 to speed up my laptop. Since reset and upgrade File Manager closes itself within a few seconds of opening. One error log is copied below.

I have read that deleting or renaming C:\WINDOWS\system32\IDTNC64.cpl or uninstalling any IDT programs can fix this problem but despite having an HP laptop I can't find the file in system32 or IDT in Control Panel. I am also getting an atibtmon.exe run-time error but this may be unrelated. Can anyone help?

```
Faulting application name: explorer.exe, version: 10.0.10586.0, time stamp: 0x5632d4c0
Faulting module name: ShellExt64.dll_unloaded, version: 0.9.1.0, time stamp: 0x4c9add55
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0000000000132d6c
Faulting process id: 0x7f0
Faulting application start time: 0x01d13f0598a3883f
Faulting application path: C:\WINDOWS\explorer.exe
Faulting module path: ShellExt64.dll
Report Id: 719ff343-8de9-4016-80a3-642dc9dbaeea
Faulting package full name:
```

Comment: "atibtmon" sounds like some monitoring software relating to your graphics card. Have you tried installing the latest versions of all hardware drivers from the respective vendors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You crash is caused by the file `ShellExt64.dll` in version 0.9.1 which can be HP CloudDrive: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Hewlett-Packard\HP CloudDrive\ShellExt64.dll` ([Source](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-update/windows-8-control-panel-and-search-crash-explorer/2a5d9a38-4b71-4a4e-b1ec-ce3eaf034ff0?auth=1)).

If you use this tool, update or remove it.

Comment: Thank you Andre. That seems to have fixed the problem. I really appreciate you taking the time to help :). At first I couldn't remove it because it said it was open but it allowed me to drag and drop to a USB drive (in case deleting it caused a problem I could replace it) then delete it..